# Batch script to replace a two word string containing parentheses

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a .h document with over 10000 lines of code. It looks like this:

```
#define GHL_NO_OF_EVENTS_CORE_2 (512uL)
#define GHL_NO_OF_CORES (1)
#define GHL_CFG_IS_GW_SAFETY_OS (1)
```

I need to change the comment `#define GHL_CFG_IS_GW_SAFETY_OS (1)` to `#define GHL_CFG_IS_GW_SAFETY_OS (0)`

I have tried a lot using this command but it seems like it doesn't work because of the parentheses:

```
powershell -Command "(gc path-to-file\Cfg.h -encoding \"Default\") -replace 'GHL_CFG_IS_GW_SAFETY_OS (1)', 'GHL_CFG_IS_GW_SAFETY_OS (0)' | Out-File -encoding \"Default\" path-to-file\Cfg.h"
```

Note: I can't escape the parentheses characters with ` or ^, it just doesn't work.

Comment: `-replace` runs a regular expression replace and the round brackets in search expression `GHL_CFG_IS_GW_SAFETY_OS (1)` are interpreted therefore as marking group and not literally. The solution working even with PowerShell 2.0 installed by default on Windows 7 with never updated PowerShell would be `%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command "(gc path-to-file\Cfg.h -encoding Ascii) -replace 'GHL_CFG_IS_GW_SAFETY_OS \(1\)', 'GHL_CFG_IS_GW_SAFETY_OS (0)' | Out-File -encoding Ascii path-to-file\Cfg.h"` with ``\`` used to escape `(` and `)` to be interpreted literally.

Comment: There is used `Ascii` instead of `"Default"` (double quotes not needed at all) because of `Default` is an unknown encoding for PowerShell 2.0. The round brackets have no regular expression meaning in the replace expression and must be escaped with a backslash for that reason only in the search expression.